# Magento 1 : All my emails go to spam in Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.8, php

I have a magento website and my emails go to spam I checked the `SPF, DKIM,` and `DNS` all are pass, I used the `default` transaction email templates but still go to `spam`!!

Can you please help us in this problem? What do you think I need to check for this problem. I found another thing our `logo image` in the emails has

https://ci4.googleusercontent.com/proxy/9_AMRUJtmC5VTVhHJZabJ0BgPBA7cMw-bO-MmcT437uZG2Q8_MgQJ-80bDDIGQNOHpk-rfvdv4NxwrScZFUcvWE8rwgFKjCsspGQXm4=s0-d-e1-ft#

before the image source is this may affect it??

Thanks

Comment: have you check 'title and alter' tags?

Comment: post your mail log, reading headers you will see where is the problem

Answer (score 1):

It is most probably related to settings of your domain and what reputation  your domain has, not anything to do with Magento.

Check this :-

https://support.google.com/a/answer/33786?hl=en-uk&hlrm=en
And check if there are any other problems, which might lead to low domain reputation.

But considering the code and mail content in particular, try following these guidelines : 
http://www.activecampaign.com/help/improving-delivery/

Here are some steps for how to avoid your e-mails being marked as spam:-
https://amasty.com/blog/5-steps-for-no-spam-e-mails-in-magento/

Comment: A service like https://www.mail-tester.com/ can also help with getting clear info about what's going on with your deliverability.